# How do I process an image at each Waypoint using the DJI SDK (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

In my app, I need to use DJI SDK to get the UIImage equivalent of the image file on the SD card for each Waypoint. So far, I've used DJIWaypointAction to take the photo, but I need to somehow get the photo back to do some processing on it.

In other words, how would I call a "non-DJIWaypointAction" method when the drone reaches each of the Waypoints. Help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no timeline action to download a picture from the SD card. You will have to listen to the waypoint events and download the picture from you own code.

Comment: I understand that, but my question was how to call my own method when the aircraft reaches the waypoint...not when the mission is being made or afterwards.

Comment: First define the waypoint mission to do something like: at waypoint #2, a picture is taken, and then pause after the picture is taken - all the above are programmed into the mission prior to taking off.  When the mission is being flown, listen to the mission events around waypoint #2. At the pause at waypoint #2, download the picture that was just taken using your own code. Just an FYI - depending on what model you are using, it is not unusual to have timeouts in downloading a picture while the aircraft is flying.